Pure functions cannot replace inequality symbols(>,<)?
A typical step-by-step calculation is as follows
f[x_] := x - Log[1 + x];
Reduce[f'[x] > 0, x, Reals]
Reduce[f'[x] < 0, x, Reals]


Pure functions cannot replace inequality symbols as follows?
f[x_] = x - Log[1 + x]
Reduce[f'[x] # 0, x, Reals] & /@ {">", "<"}

f[x_] = x - Log[1 + x]
Reduce[f'[x] # 0, x, Reals] & /@ {> , <}



You can try using Replace as in Reduce[f'[x] > 0,x,Reals]/.{Less->Greater,Greater->Less} here is screen shot.  https://i.sstatic.net/7LkqgteK.png  not sure if this is what you were looking for.

I do not know what you want the output to be. If you just want < to become > then just use Less->Greater  It will be better to say given this, how to make it becomes that. Then things will be more clear to the reader what you trying to do.

Try this Reduce[#[1, 0]] & /@ {Greater, Less} with result True, False. In other words, full function names are needed.

The problem comes before trying replacement.  Consider the FullForm of just the predicate in your Reduce.
FullForm[(f'[x]  #  0) &]
(* Function[Times[Derivative[1][f][x],Slot[1],0]] *)

You can see that the #argument, Slot[1], is multiplied by f'[x] and 0.  Not applied.  We can apply the argument instead,
Reduce[#[f'[x], 0], x, Reals] & /@ {">", "<"}

but we are still faced with the error Reduce::naqs: >[(f^\[Prime])[x],0] is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities..
The remaining issue is that ">" and "<" are strings, not symbols.  But you can't remove the "quotes" and get valid Mathematica either.  Instead, you need to know
FullForm[a > b]
(* Greater[a, b] *)

So, what you're aiming for is
Reduce[#[f'[x], 0], x, Reals] & /@ {Greater, Less}
(* {x<-1||x>0,-1<x<0} *)

